# Image preprocessing with OpenCV (OCR Tesseract)

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to develop simple PC application which allows to extract metadata from identity document. Images aren't really good (in further they will be good). I want to preprocess image for tesseract, and it correctly extracts only 15% of the document. I would like to improve this percentage.

1. Source image
   [image]

2. My code

   ```
   String inputFilePath = path;
    img = Imgcodecs.imread(inputFilePath);
    Imgcodecs.imwrite( selectedFolder + "\\preprocess\\"+b.getSelectedValue().toString()+"_original.png", img);
    Mat kernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(30,5));
    //Applying erosion on the Image
    Imgproc.cvtColor(img, imgGray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgcodecs.imwrite(selectedFolder + "\\preprocess\\"+b.getSelectedValue().toString()+"2_imgGray.png", imgGray);

    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imgGray,imgGaussianBlur, new Size(3, 3),0);
    Imgcodecs.imwrite(selectedFolder + "\\preprocess\\"+b.getSelectedValue().toString()+"3_imgGaussianBlur.png", imgGray);

    Imgproc.threshold(imgGaussianBlur, imgThreshold, 0,255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV+Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU); 
    Imgcodecs.imwrite(selectedFolder + "\\preprocess\\"+b.getSelectedValue().toString()+"5_imgThreshold.png", imgThreshold);
   ```

Comment: rotating it upright would probably help the most. why don't you try that first?

Comment: How can I automatically rotate image depending this position ?